# can't change user avatar

Tags: python, django, forms, avatar

In my app I allow users to have a profile avatar and I allow users to change their avatar from their profile.

for the user profile answer the following view:

```
class CustomerDetailUpdateView1(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    model = User
    form_class = CustomerDetailUpdateForm1
    template_name = 'customer/customer-profile1.html'

    def get_object(self):
        # print(forms.context_data)
        return self.request.user

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("customer:customer-update")
```

the code of form is:

```
class CustomerDetailUpdateForm1(ModelForm):

   class Meta:

        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'full_name', 'avatar', 'country', 'city', 'address', 'phone_number' ]
        widgets = {
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'full_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'country': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

in template:

```
<div>
   {{ form.as_p }}
</div>
```

everything works except when the user tries to change his avatr. error does not occur BUT the avatar does not change.

can someone help me with the explanation what is the problem ???

Comment: is your form submitting successfully ?

Comment: yes, sub success.
I understand why you ask)) form.as_p is inside the form tag.
i solved the problem.
i addes in tag form "enctype="multipart/form-data""
and everything started working

Comment: great then :) sad I could not get point on this question :D